# Shape on string for function in range $(-L,+L)$

Tags: waves, string, boundary-conditions

What combination of wave equation solution should I assume for string fixed at $x=-L$ and $x=+L$. I was trying with for example:
$$\psi_m(x,t)=\cos(k_mx+\alpha_m)[A_m\cos(\omega_mt)+B_m\sin(\omega_mt)].$$
but with every type of function initial conditions doesn't help with making coefficients a zero.
Do you have any ideas what combination I should use for function in range $(-L,+L)$ where one of boundary conditions (velocity) is given as even function?

Here what I was trying to do:
[image: My solution-doesn't work]

Comment: I have seen the work you have done in the earlier version of this question, so I am inclined to help you. But have you checked the textbooks and/or other resources on the topic?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769688/2451

Comment: Yes, but I only find information on how to solve this case for x from 0 to L. Where x=0 helps a lot because it makes some coefficients zero, I was trying on some combinations but there is always a problem to find all coefficients. I think that I only need a hint with initial form of function $\psi(x,t)$ then I know what to make with the rest of solution. Thank you for you answer

Comment: The case of 0 to L can be directly translated to your case, and it is also easy to write down how to get the even v.s. odd solutions in that case.

Comment: I've tried different ways but apparently I don't see how I can translate it to my problem.

Comment: You should showcase the different ways to write down the problem, that you have tried. Then we can see how to help

Answer (score 1):

For Dirichlet boundary conditions, the even modes are of the form $\cos(kx)$ must satisfy (setting $L=1$):
$$
\cos k = 0
$$
so that:
$$
k_n = \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi
$$
with $n\in\mathbb N^*$ by convention.

The odd modes are of the form $\sin(l x)$ so satisfy:
$$
\sin l = 0
$$
with:
$$
l_n = n\pi
$$
with $n\in\mathbb N^*$.

Thus any function $\psi(x)$ can be written as:
$$
\psi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\cos(k_nx)+B_n\sin(l_n x)
$$
with:
$$
\begin{align}
A_n &= \int_{-1}^1 \psi(x)\cos(k_nx)dx & B_n &= \int_{-1}^1 \psi(x)\sin(l_nx)dx \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
In particular, if $\psi$ is even, $B=0$ and if $\psi$ is odd, $A=0$. More rigorously, this can be proven mathematically for $\psi$ in $L^2((-1,1))$, the convergence of the sum to be understood in terms of the $L^2$ norm and the integrals as inner products with the basis functions.

Usually, it is simpler to rather consider the domain $[0,1]$ instead of $[-1,1]$ since the modes have a unified expression in terms of $\sin$. In particular, you recover that the spectrum of $-\partial_x^2$ is still:
$$
\left(\frac{\pi m}{2}\right)^2 
$$
with $m\in\mathbb N^*$ (the $1/2$ is because $[-1,1]$ is twice as long as $[0,1]$).

Hope this helps.

**Answer to comment**

Your goal is to solve the Cauchy problem of the d'Alembert wave equation:
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_t^2\psi-\partial_x^2\psi &= 0 \\
\psi(t=0) &= f\\
\partial_t\psi(t=0)&=g
\end{align}
$$
The coefficients $A_n,B_n$ are now time dependent and satisfy the ODE's:
$$
\begin{align}
\ddot A_n &= -k_n^2A_n & \ddot B_n &= -l_n^2B_n 
\end{align}
$$
and the initial conditions are given by expanding $f,g$ into modes:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n^e\cos(k_nx)+f_n^o\sin(l_n x) \tag{2}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n(0)\cos(k_nx)+B_n(0)\sin(l_n x) \\
g(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n^e\cos(k_nx)+g_n^o\sin(l_n x) \tag{3}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dot A_n(0)\cos(k_nx)+\dot B_n(0)\sin(l_n x)
\end{align}
$$

so you get:
$$
\begin{align}
A_n &= f_n^e\cos(k_nt)+\frac{g_n^e}{k_n}\sin(k_n t) \\
B_n &= f_n^o\cos(l_nt)+\frac{g_n^o}{l_n}\sin(l_n t)
\end{align}
$$

In your case:
$$
\begin{align}
f &= 0 & g &= 1-x^2
\end{align}
$$
so you get:
$$
\begin{align}
f_n^e &= 0 & f_n^o &= 0 \\
g_n^e &= \frac{4(-1)^{n+1}}{k_n^3} & g_n^o &= 0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I will try it in my solution

Comment: Read the OP's earlier question. He needs to incorporate time evolution.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent The previous question was closed and the OP didn't ask about the time evolution in this question. Anyway, I think that this question will be closed soon as well.

Comment: Well I thought maybe this would help with the solution. I still need a time dependent function

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent please if you have an idea how to solve my problem give me a hint :(

Comment: @LPZ can I ask what means $g^{e}_{n}$ ?

Comment: $g^o,g^e$ are the coefficients of $g$ in the expansion into even and odd modes respectively, defined implicitly in (2) and (3). You calculate them from $g$ using the same formula as in (1).

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to use it in my case

Answer (score 0):

You started with
$$\tag1x\in(-L,+L)\quad\bigwedge\quad y(x,t=0)=0\quad\bigwedge\quad\dot y(x,0)=V_0\left[1-\left(\frac{x}{L}\right)^2\right]$$
The constant term that appears in your Fourier expansion is a problem.

Let $z=\dfrac\pi{2L}(x+L)$ and $q(z,t)=y(x,t)=y(-L+\frac{2Lz}{\pi},t)$ so that
$$\tag2z\in(0,\pi)\quad\bigwedge\quad q(z,t=0)=0\quad\bigwedge\quad\dot q(z,0)=V_0z(1-\frac z\pi)$$
This way, $q$ is in the most natural form, because the boundary conditions means that
\begin{align}\tag3
q(z,t)&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty A_r\sin [(2r+1)z]\sin(\omega_rt)\\
\implies\qquad\tag4\dot
q(z,t)&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty \omega_rA_r\sin[(2r+1)z]\cos(\omega_rt)
\end{align}
where we only need to care about the odd terms, as written above, because you have symmetry.

I thus leave to you to work out a few things:

1. This scheme has all your even solutions, that are zero at $x=\pm L$
2. What are the appropriate $\omega_r$ so that you can even compare and fit the Fourier series.
3. How to convert the answer back to $y(x,t)$
4. How to directly get $y(x,t)$ from your original form.

Comment: I was also trying with changing coordinates but I don't know what to do with this function q(z,t), how to transfer it back to x, or how to make it work on graph for -L to +L

Comment: I gave the explicit conversion rule between z and x